# When No Active Bounties, the List is Redundant!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-declined, bounties

Right now (at least as of two minutes ago) on Meta, there aren't any questions with active bounties. I clicked on the Featured tab, and this is what I see:

[image: No Active Bounties - Featured Tab]

Looks normal, right? So I clicked on the "complete list" link, and now this is what I see:
[image: No Active Bounties - Complete List]

It doesn't look "wrong", but how is "recent questions" different from "all questions" in terms of Featured questions, even with reputation?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the first answer, I now realize that the Recent Questions Featured tab indicates bounties ending soon, while that of All Questions shows all of bounties. However, now I have a small feature/change request - wouldn't it be better to not have that link from Recent Questions if there aren't any bounties at all?

**UPDATE #2:** Also, [Wim](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138483/wim) had a very good comment:

> I think he means that, when both lists are empty, it's a little pointless to link to "All Questions". A "No Featured questions at this time" message would be more clear I guess.

Is that a good idea? I think so!

Comment: What's wrong with your resolution? Is it all squished like that?

Comment: You obviously need more tabs open, then everything will be right in the universe again!

Comment: @squillman @random sorry, i was on another comp (not on my main one), that's why it looks horrible - oh and the tabs, see here: http://absolutely2nothing.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/obsession.png

Comment: You definitely need to start using the RSS feeds to keep up with conversations, instead of keeping the tags open. I'm assuming that you have "work" browser that we can see, right?

Comment: @voyager well, those 3 pictures were all from the other computer (not my main one), but that's actually a great idea! I'm going to try that right now! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're missing the **[bug]** tag.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) and you will understand. The featured list shows by default only one page with the questions where the bounty will end soon. If you want to see more than one page you have to click the "See All (featured) Questions" link (aka "complete list").

If the "pointless link" is bugging you, then I suggest: Don't bother! This is only an issue on Meta. I doubt that this will become visible on SO. There are always bounties.

Comment: I think he means that, when both lists are empty, it's a little pointless to link to "All Questions". A "No Featured questions at this time" message would be more clear I guess.

Comment: @Wim: Not worth changing that. It's only an issue on Meta.